# Rewriting a hyperbolic equation in standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$9x^2-4y^2-72x$ = 0

How would that be done?

So far, I got up to

$\frac{9(x^2-8x)}1-\frac{4(y-0)^2}1=0$

Comment: Complete the square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$9(x^2-8x)-4y^2=0\implies 9\left(x-4\right)^2-4y^2=144\iff\frac{(x-4)^2}{4^2}-\frac{y^2}{6^2}=1$$